# Unable to add time picker time to textfield in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, timepicker

I have created time picker in alert and in ok action i want to add selected time to regarding textfield, and is it possible to hide AM, PM from time picker, if possible how? i need to show only hours and minutes without AM, PM in time picker. please help me in the code.

here is my code:

```
 func timePicker(){

    let vc = UIViewController()
    vc.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 200,height: 200)
    let timePicker = UIDatePicker(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    //dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
    timePicker.datePickerMode = .time

    vc.view.addSubview(timePicker)
    let addTimePickerAlert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

    addTimePickerAlert.setValue(vc, forKey: "contentViewController")
    let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in

        self.hoursMinutesTextField.text = dateFormatter.string(from: timePicker.date)
        print("time textfield \(self.hoursMinutesTextField.text)")
    })
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: {
        (action : UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
    })
    addTimePickerAlert.addAction(ok)
    addTimePickerAlert.addAction(cancelAction)

    self.present(addTimePickerAlert, animated: true)
}

func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool 
{

 self.timePicker()
    return true
}
```

please help me in the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed set `dateFormat`  to `dateFormatter` that's why you getting **" "**

Uncomment this line in your code its work

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm" // 04:57

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm" // 16:57
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: yes i am able to use 24hrs format but that time in not displaying in textfield

Comment: Please check you textfield @IBOutlet because with this code I check it by setting selected time in textfield alert and it's working fine.

Comment: no my textfield in view while tapping button alert time picker will display  in that i am selecting time from alert is to add in textfield

Comment: @Swift either set in alert textfield or uiview textfield both are same.

Comment: in alert there is no textfield only timepicker is there the selected time should display in textfield which is in view

Comment: @Swift you can see the output of set selected date value in view textfield and it's also working.

Answer (score 1):

In picker setup change locale to have always 24h format:

```
timePicker.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_GB")
```

Comment: thank you, its working but unable to add that time to textfield, please look into it once

Comment: you need to make your question clearer, what exactly happens when you try to put data text? print("time textfield \(self.hoursMinutesTextField.text)")

Comment: i have selected some time and i tap on ok but that time is not adding in textfield

Comment: Did you try to debug it? are you sure you are picking time from correct picker? Where are you presenting timePicker?

Comment: i am presenting time picker in alert, and yes i am selecting time but which is not adding

Comment: did you try breakpoints? what is your data formatter correct?

Comment: you are printing `timePicker.date` and date is not showing? nothing?

Comment: yes, dateFormatter.string(from: timePicker.date) shows nothing

Comment: @Swift check my answer it's working fine just you missed one thing

Comment: @Lu_ you helped me in time 24hrs formate thank u its working